# Here-Maps Autocomplete return incorrect results for Postcodes

Tags: autocomplete, here-api, here-maps-rest, heremaps

we uses the Here-Technologies REST-API (Geocoding & Search API V7) for Autocomplete.
As example is I search für "Arnhem" we will get a correct result for Arnhem (NL).
But when we search Postcodes the results are not very good.
Here I have two examples:

1.) Search for "6828" or "6828 CD" (Arnhem, NL) will do not return any result. This Problem is present for other cities and countries, too.
In Netherlands we had the most problems with Postcodes. In Germany, Austria, .. we have sometimes this problem.

2.) Search for "2300" (Copenhagen) will only return a result if the value "in" is filled with "DNK".

If we search this values into the in-house map of Here-Technologies (https://wego.here.com) we will get the correct results for all.

Does someone had any idea what we can do to get better results?

Thank you!

Comment: that feeling, when HERE Developer Support edits your question instead of answering it....